# How to create user after login with facebook

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using facebook auth to login. my issue is that I am trying to create user after login on firebase.
I am using angular 2 and AngularFire.
I want to store data to firebase with user info
My code is :

```
  private _changeState(user: any = null) {
    if (user) {
      this.isAuth = true;
      this.user = this._getUserInfo(user);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);

    }
```

where user have uid,pic,email...

Comment: ...and what exactly is the question? any errors? where is the rest of the code?

Comment: "my issue is that I am trying to create user after login on firebase" - that is not an issue, it is a task.

Comment: I am trying to store user data on firebase

Comment: we know that, but that´s a task. you can hire a developer for that, or you can tell us what you have tried so far. where is your code about storing the user in firebase? what does not work?

Answer (score 1):

that just what was needed to do

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```